# "card" tag is too meta, time to kill it?

Tags: discussion, tags

[card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/card) makes no sense as a tag, it should be killed as we have [video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video) for video stuff and the various wireless tags for wireless.

Perhaps synonyming it to [hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hardware)?

Comment: Completely agreed. This is probably a side effect of people typing spaced phrases like `video card`, `graphics card`, `wireless card`, etc into the tag box without realising that it's space-delimited.

Comment: Blue sky: could this possibly be a useful synonym for "hardware"? I see it's used for video cards, tv tuner cards, and so on. Makes me think these questions are about "peripherals" (hardware).

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo excellent idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have removed (edited out) all the [card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/card) tags out of networking ([network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network), [wireless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wireless) cards) posts and have merged all remaining card tags to [graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/graphics) it felt that video was too generic since it can relate to video capture cards or graphics cards, all video tagged questions where edited out to remove card also.

If you see any further [card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/card) tags running loose kill it asap so that the tag is also dropped.